# Verifying ODE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this first order ODE I want to solve :

$$ y'= \sqrt{1-x^2} y $$
with initial value $y(0)=2 $

Here are my calculations:
The general solution is

$ y(x) = c \exp ( \int \sqrt{(1-x^2)} dx) $

=$ c \exp ( \frac{ arcsin(x)+x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{2} ) $

with the initial value:
$y(0)= c ( \exp(0)) =! 2$
$ \rightarrow c=2 $

so it comes to:

$ y(x)= 2 \exp (  \frac{ arcsin(x)+x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{2} )$

Can someone tell me if my solution is right?
And is the domain of definition $ (0, \infty) $?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: No.  $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a) \exp(b)$, not $\exp(a)+\exp(b)$.

Comment: As for domain, what happens when $x^2 > 1$?

Comment: oh, yes that was stupid! i have edited it!

Comment: if $ x^2 >1 $ than the root will be negative..so it is $ (0,1)$ ?

Comment: The domain is $(-1,1)$.